# RegEx to split after character or character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string such as '12:00am' OR it could sometimes be '12:00pm'.
I need to add a space before the 'a' OR 'p' so it would look like '12:00 am' or '12:00 pm'.
Is there a RegEx to do so to include both characters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a lookbehind to match `am` or `pm` with a digit before it. Then replace it with a space followed by the match.

```js
let times = ['12:00am', '12:01pm', '12:02 am', '12:03 pm']

console.log(times.map(time => time.replace(/(?<=\d)[ap]m/ig, ' $&')));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do that way as well

```
"12:00am".replace(/[ap]/ig," $&" )  
// 12:00 am

"12:00pm".replace(/[ap]/ig," $&" )
// 12:00 pm
```